# Android send string with socket error in connecting

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to communicate with the computer using a socket.
I created the server with Python and I am trying to access it using Android (Java).

I tried to connect to the server using `Socket client = new Socket (" xxx.xxx.xxxx ", 3425);` but it throws me an error and I can not figure out what it is. Can anyone show me how to communicate with the computer? I have been searching for more than two hours (I'm not kidding) and I constantly have an error in the `Socket client = new Socket (" xxx.xxx.xxxx ", 3425);`

My error in the line is `at com.example.computer.MainActivity.Send(MainActivity.java:48)`
from IoException

My server in python:

```
import socket, time

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind((" xxx.xxx.xxxx ", 3425))

soc.listen(5)
(client, (ipNum, portNum)) = soc.accept()


print("Client connected")

while True:
    print(client.recv(40))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

**Maybe it because I didn't ask permission for internet?**

Comment: Is there any message from your Java code (i.e. in a `catch` block)?

Comment: Yes. IoException

Comment: But what does the `IOException` say?  i.e., what does `printStackTrace()` on the caught exception say?  Like `catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());}`